# Google Developer Console... no promote to prod action?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-console

This is my first ever Android app and it has just completed the beta testing phase and now ready to go live. When I go the 'PRODUCTION' tab under the APK menu, it says:

> You currently don't have the necessary rights to make changes to APKs
>   in production. Please ask the account owner to grant you access. The
>   contact email address is xxxxx@xxxxx.com.

I am not the owner of this account. They created it and made me a member so I could publish the app but there is no option to do this. I read you can 'Promote to Prod' from the beta tab... if I click 'Switch to advanced mode' there is no option for this under 'Actions'. Only 'Move to Alpha' or 'Deactivate'.

I've Googled this but found nothing. Do I need to be given ownership rights to be able to do this? Or do I have to do something else? Sorry if this is silly - it's my first ever app!

Comment: Does nobody know? :s It's read to go but there's no option to promote to production? Do I have to be the account owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My account was assigned as Product Lead, which by default doesn't allow for promote to prod unless the right is given to you. Only beta and alpha are allowed.

I got somebody who was the Release Manager to promote to prod. Basically it was a rights issue.